# SQL - Why doesn't using alias in Group By doesn't work in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Why can't I use Alias even after nesting the code, it seems to not work, I used a different approach which works but doesn't look good.

**This doesn't work**

```
SELECT Year,
       Number_of_rides
FROM   (SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime]) AS Year,
               COUNT (*)                   AS Number_of_rides
        FROM   [dbo].[Citi-Bike-Trip-Data]) AS x
GROUP  BY x.Year,
          x.Number_of_rides
ORDER  BY Year ASC
```

**This works**

```
SELECT 
     DATEPART(YEAR, 
      [starttime]) AS Year,
      COUNT (*) AS Number_of_rides 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Citi-Bike-Trip-Data]
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime])
```

Comment: First code block looks like it get wrong syntax.

Comment: This has nothing to do with aliasing, the subquery in your first query is invalid because you select a column not in an aggregate function, nor in a group by.

Comment: Probably a matter of opinion, but I think the second query is much easier to read (even if the first were correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by others, the problem is not with the alias. You are missing `group by` in the subquery, which is required since you are using `count` there:

```
SELECT [Year],
       Number_of_rides
FROM   (SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime]) AS [Year],
               COUNT (*)                   AS Number_of_rides
        FROM   [dbo].[Citi-Bike-Trip-Data]
        GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime])) AS x
GROUP  BY x.Year,
          x.Number_of_rides
ORDER  BY [Year] ASC
```

Since the data is already grouped in the subquery, you don't need to group again:

```
SELECT [Year],
       Number_of_rides
FROM   (SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime]) AS [Year],
               COUNT (*)                   AS Number_of_rides
        FROM   [dbo].[Citi-Bike-Trip-Data]
        GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [starttime])) AS x
ORDER  BY [Year] ASC
```

And since the data is already grouped and already exactly what you want, you really don't need to select it again, so:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, starttime) AS [Year],
       COUNT (*)                   AS Number_of_rides
FROM   dbo.Citi-Bike-Trip-Data
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, starttime)
ORDER BY [Year]
```

Which is almost like your original second version, but only adding in the `order by`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` actually is allowed to use the `SELECT` alias

Comment: Even though `year` isn't a reserved keyword, I would discourage its use as alias. `startYear`, for example, would be more descriptive and less likely to cause confusion (if only because of syntax highlighting)

Comment: I have updated the example to use the `select` alias in the `order by` clause. Probably I would also avoid year as a column name generally as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to `group by` in your subquery, so use this:

```sql
SELECT datepart(year, x.starttime) as Year, x.Number_of_rides 
from 
(
    select [starttime], COUNT (*) AS Number_of_rides 
    FROM [dbo].[Citi-Bike-Trip-Data]
    GROUP BY [starttime]
) as x
Order by x.[starttime] ASC
```

Only select the columns in your subquery, and then use `datepart(year, x.starttime)` in your outer query would be a good solution.

Or a `cte` would do same thing.

If you need to `group by` year, then the only solution I can think of is using `group by datepart(year, starttime)` as your second query, as you can only use computed column names in `order by` clause, but not in `where` or `group by`.